# Calculate Elasticsearch Query Complexity (Scalabilty)

Tags: database, algorithm, performance, elasticsearch, time

I'm doing a project with ElasticSearch and the goal of the project is to optimise the time of request, now I'm trying with 1Go of data and the request took about 1200ms, I wanna calculate the time with 60Go of data, I'm asking if there is techniques to calculate complexity of my query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not as easy as extrapolating, i.e. if the request takes 1200ms with 1GB of data, it doesn't mean it'll take 60 times more with 60GB. Going from 1GB to 60GB of data has unpredictable effects and totally depends on the hardware you're running your ES on. The server might be OK for 1GB but not for 60GB, so you might need to scale out, but you won't really know until you have that big an amount of data.

The only way to really know is to get to 60GB of data (and scale your cluster appropriately ([start big & scale down](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sizing-elasticsearch)) and do your testing on a real amount of data.